# What is the dual of the space L-infinity ($L^\infty$)?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Duals of $l^\infty$ and $L^{\infty}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/the-duals-of-l-infty-and-l-infty)

In learning real analysis, I do understand that the dual of $L^\infty$ cannot be $L^1$ because the latter is separable, whereas the former is not separable. So the double dual of $L^1$ is strictly larger than $L^1$ (non-reflexivity).  See for example this question:

[Dual of $\ell_{\infty}$ is not $\ell_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35301/dual-of-ell-infty-is-not-ell-1)

However, I am not able to find in my textbooks etc. the precise space which is the dual of $L^\infty(\Bbb R)$.

I want to know exactly what it is. I would very much appreciate help.

Comment: The short answer is that the nontrivial elements of the dual aren't describable without some form of the axiom of choice. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22661/explicit-element-of-ell-infty-ell1 .

Comment: It's described in IV.8.16 of Dunford and Schwartz' *Linear Operators, Part I* as a certain space of bounded, scalar-valued set functions.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/the-duals-of-l-infty-and-l-infty).

Comment: weaker statement than what quaochu said : it contains elements that cannot reasonnably be represented as functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these helpful answers.